# PostgreSQL, не выполняется запрос создания таблицы

Tags: postgresql

Postgres не создает таблицу.

Запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles {
    user_id int not null,
    role_id int not null,

    foreign key (user_id) references n_user(id),
    foreign key (role_id) references roles(id),

    unique (user_id, role_id)
};
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "roles"
```

Данные в таблицу roles вставлены так, и они есть:

```
INSERT INTO roles values (1, 'ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO roles values (2, 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```

Comment: Он как-то обосновывает своё "нежелание"?

Comment: ERROR: type "key" does not exist
  Позиция: 100

Comment: Добавляйте такие вещи в вопрос. Ну и да, у вас как минимум какое-то мифическое слово `foreing` рядом с `key`, на который он жалуется.

Comment: Ох, спасибо. Извиняюсь за нелепость.

Comment: Обновил вопрос с указанием новой ошибки.

Comment: Ну вы её прочитайте хотя бы.

Comment: Прочитал, но не понял, что значит.

Comment: Что в таблице `roles` нет уникального констрейнта на ключ(-и), к которому(-ым) вы делаете внешний ключ.

Comment: Мм, а как это поправить?

Comment: Создать его, разумеется.

Comment: ALTER TABLE roles ADD CONSTRAINT positive_id CHECK (id > 0); - так?

Comment: Нет, не так. Это не уникальный констрейнт. (Вообще это кривой перевод, наверное: точнее будет "констрейнт на уникальность".)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75055/discussion-between-timur-musharapov-and-d-side).

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```
ALTER TABLE roles ADD CONSTRAINT unique_id UNIQUE (id);
```

Answer (score 1):

В Postgres внешним ключем могут являться только столбцы с уникальным значением. Для того что бы сделать внешний ключ на таблицу  roles(id), тебе необходимо сделать его уникальным.

Одно из решений:

```
ALTER TABLE roles ADD CONSTRAINT unique_id UNIQUE (id);
```

Но я бы тебе рекомендовал  поле id в таблице roles сделать primary key.
Это обеспечит уникальность, а также в автоматическом режиме на него будет создан индекс, что поможет тебе в будущем когда будешь использовать JOIN.